# Is it posible to customize UITextField selection pins shape?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm trying to find way to customize these little `UITextField` 'pins':

[image]

How can I change their shape?

`UITextField` has a `tintColor` for all selection and pins, but I cannot find anywhere, how to make custom shape for them.